# Реинициализация JS после выполнения AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

В разрабатываемом проекта на WP использую плагин Search Filter Pro для поиска по произвольным типам поста и таксономиям.

Ссылка на пример
[тыц](http://tour.ananas.net.ua/cms/sample-page/)

На :hover висит код, который на каждой записи поднимает вверх черную плашку. Плагин дружит с ajax. После вывода результатов запроса естественно не подгружает JS.

Разработчик предлогает такой способ обнаружения запуска AJAX и подгрузки скрипта:

```
`//detects the start of an ajax request being made
$(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function(){
  console.log("ajax start");
});

//detects when the ajax request has finished and the content has been updated
// - add scripts that apply to your results here
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    console.log("ajax complete");
    //so load your lightbox or JS scripts here again
});

//an event fired when S&F is initialised and S&F scripts have been loaded
$(document).on("sf:init", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    console.log("S&F JS initialised");
});`
```

Я использую версию плагина 1.4.3 и у меня данное решение не работает.
Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Выводит какие-нибуть ошибки?

Comment: Ошибки не выводит. Все работает, только не подгружает js код который отвечает за анимацию при наведении.

Comment: Покажите ваши сборки плагинов, не все из них совместимы друг с другом, бывает что ошибку как раз не пишет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение которое представленно на сайте автора [ссылка на сайт](http://www.designsandcode.com/wordpress-plugins/search-filter-pro/faqs/)

Надо было просто обернуть в анонимную функцию:

```
    (function ($) {

    "use strict";

    $(function () {
        $(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function () {
            console.log("ajax start");
        });
        $(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function () {
            console.log("ajax complete");

        });
        $(document).on("sf:init", ".searchandfilter", function () {
            console.log("S&F JS initialised");
        });
    });

}(jQuery));
```